# Insert into a table with auto_increment, but return other column as LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table with an auto incrementing primary key. I want to insert a row into it, but return something else as `LAST_INSERT_ID`. Reading the manual, I thought it was possible to do:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    number BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO test (number) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(50));

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I want this to return 50, but it returns 1 instead.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-insert-id.html) states that:

> The return value of mysql_insert_id() can be simplified to the following sequence:
>
> 1. If there is an AUTO_INCREMENT column, and an automatically generated value was successfully inserted, return the first such value.
> 2. If LAST_INSERT_ID(expr) occurred in the statement, return expr, even if there was an AUTO_INCREMENT column in the affected table.
> 3. The return value varies depending on the statement used. When called after an INSERT statement:
>
>    - If there is an AUTO_INCREMENT column in the table, and there were some explicit values for this column that were successfully inserted into the table, return the last of the explicit values.
>
>    When called after an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement:
>
>    - If there is an AUTO_INCREMENT column in the table and there were some explicit successfully inserted values or some updated values, return the last of the inserted or updated values.

If I'm interpreting point *2.* correctly, my query should work and should return 50, not 1. But it looks like point *1.* precedes point *2.*

Is there any other way achieve this without having to run multiple queries?

Answer (score 0):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` - Value of the AUTOINCREMENT column for the last INSERT 
(automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column),

it is from [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html) page.

It mean that you have use this function like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    number BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO test (number) VALUES (200);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+

INSERT INTO test (number) VALUES (100);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
```

But:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (50, 50);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+

select * from test;
+----+--------+
| id | number |
+----+--------+
|  1 |    200 |
|  2 |    100 |
| 50 |     50 |
+----+--------+
```

It is because id 50 was not generated by mysql...

Comment: I know the normal use of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. But I'm using `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`, which is a function that returns `expr` _and at the same time sets last_insert_id for the current session to `expr`_.

Common example is: `UPDATE table SET number = LAST_INSERT_ID(number + 1);` which increments `number` and on the same time returns it's value as `last_insert_id`.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: But your example is interesting anyway. Didn't know that.